# Excel: How to dynamically change text within a formula using text from a reference cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following line I am working on:

=VLOOKUP(B16,PI_Rank_**Ferox**,2,FALSE)

I am trying to take text in the formula (the example shows the word Ferox) and make it dynamically changed based on what's happening in another cell (the text in the cell H3).

So if H3 shows the word Griffin, I want the cell to change to this:

=VLOOKUP(B16,PI_Rank_**Griffin**,2,FALSE)

If H3 shows the words Slasher II, I want it to look like this:

=VLOOKUP(B16,PI_Rank_**Slasher_II**,2,FALSE)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A use for the `INDIRECT` function.

Try:

```
=VLOOKUP(B16,INDIRECT("PI_Rank_" & H3),2,FALSE)
```

*Note that `INDIRECT` is a volatile function, and if you have a large number of formulas using this, it may slow down your worksheet calculations*

Comment: This worked! I knew there had to be a simple command to get it to recognize just the text in a cell and add it to the end. I did add a SUBSTITUTE command to make up for the spaces, but otherwise the simple answer is the correct one this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
=VLOOKUP(D2,IFS($F$13="Ferox",PI_Rank_Ferox,$F$13="Griffin",PI_Rank_Griffin,$F$13="Slasher II",PI_Rank_Slasher_II),2,FALSE)

Please note that *PI_Rank_Ferox*, *PI_Rank_Griffin* and *PI_Rank_Slasher_II* are added as table range instead of text.
[image]

Comment: This is an option with a small number of words to pick from, but my overall sheet has almost 300 possibilities. I appreciate the suggestion, it's just too much in the long run. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is:
= VLOOKUP(B16, CHOOSE(H4, PI_Rank_Ferox, PI_Rank_Griffin, PI_Rank_Slasher_II), 2, FALSE)

where cell H4 contains the index number 1-3 of your selection in cell H3.

If you want to make it really beautiful and easily extendable, make a table with 1 column that contains all the values you want your user to be able to select.
Create a named reference (Formulas->Name Manager->New) and in the Refers to you type: =INDEX(<your table name[Column name]>, 0).
Now, make cell H3 a data validation cell,which values are based on a list. In the source field, type the name of the named reference you just created.
And at last, cell H4, type: IFERROR(Match(H3, <your table name[Column name]>, 0), 1)